# Why is my array empty outside of useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios, use-effect

```
const [allJobs, setAllJobs] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3002/api/jobs')
            .then(res => setAllJobs(res.data));
        allJobs.map((job, i) => {
            if (job.language.toLowerCase() === currentLanguage) {
                jobsArray.push(job)
            }
            return jobsArray;
        })
        console.log(jobsArray)
    }, []);
```

```
const displayJobs = allJobs.map((job, i) => (
    <Accordion className={classes.accordion} expanded={expanded === `panel${i+1}`} onChange={handleChange(`panel${i+1}`)} key={i}>
// display stuff here
 ));
```

Basically what I do is fetch all the jobs from my MongoDB and save them in "allJobs" state.

Then, based on a string field they have, representing the language they're written in, I need to filter only the ones that have the same language as my 'currentLanguage' var

A good approach I consider to be also using filter:

```
useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('http://localhost:3002/api/jobs')
       .then(res => setAllJobs(res.data));

   let result = allJobs.filter(job => job.language.toLowerCase() === currentLanguage);
   console.log(result)
}, []);
```

This returns me what I need inside the useEffect function, but outside of it it's just an empty array. I've tried simply returning it, but it doesn't solve it.

From what I've read, it might have to do with asynchronicity but I don't know what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've read, `setState` is asynchronous (and so is Axios). That's why you're getting unexpectedly empty arrays with your code.

You'll want something like this to play nicely with hooks.

- `allJobs` is `null` to begin with; nothing has been loaded.
- The `useEffect` has no deps, so it's run exactly once, on component mount.
- `filteredJobs` is memoized; whenever `allJobs` or `currentLanguage` changes, it's recomputed.
- Make sure you have [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) configured, so you adhere to [the Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

```
function JobComponent() {
  const [allJobs, setAllJobs] = useState(null);
  const [currentLanguage, setCurrentLanguage] = useState("fi");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3002/api/jobs").then((res) => setAllJobs(res.data));
  }, []);

  const filteredJobs = React.useMemo(
    () => (allJobs || []).filter((job) => job.language.toLowerCase() === currentLanguage),
    [allJobs, currentLanguage],
  );

  if (allJobs === null) {
    return <>Loading</>;
  }

  return filteredJobs.map((job, i) => (
    <Accordion
      className={classes.accordion}
      expanded={expanded === `panel${i + 1}`}
      onChange={handleChange(`panel${i + 1}`)}
      key={i}
    >
      // display stuff here
    </Accordion>
  ));
}
```